# Keyword not found where expected

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

How do i fix keyword not found where expected error!please anyone help
Thanks

FROM keyword not found where expected" while executing the query

```
String query = "select  bc.institution_code,bc.branch_code,tmp.order_channel,tmp.order_root_div,"
        + "count(ls.session_id) as tenlogincount from branch bc,login_session ls,(select    a.session_id,a.branch_id,"
        + "b.order_channel,c.order_root_div from(select session_id,property_value as branch_id"
        + "from login_session_property where property_name = 'branchID') a,(select session_id,"
        + "property_value as order_channel from login_session_property where property_name = 'orderChannel') b,"
        + "(select  session_id,property_value as order_root_div from login_session_property"
        + "where property_name = 'orderRootDiv') c where    a.session_id = b.session_id"
        + "and  b.session_id = c.session_id) tmp where  to_char(ls.creation_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ?"
        + "and  ls.type_id in  (select type_id from login_type where type_name like '%customer_login_type%')"
        + "and  ls.session_id = tmp.session_id and  bc.branch_id = tmp.branch_id"
        + "and  ((to_char(ls.creation_date,'HH24MI') <= ? and to_char(ls.last_update,'HH24MI') >= ?"
        + "and  ls.validity <> 0) or    (to_char(ls.creation_date,'HH24MI') <= ?"
        + "and  to_char(ls.expiration_date,'HH24MI') >= ? and   ls.validity = 0)) group by bc.institution_code,"
        + "bc.branch_code,tmp.order_channel,tmp.order_root_div";
```

Comment: I’d run your query for you, but the tables you’re referring to don’t exist. You should consider adding in the create table commands for the snippet to be complete. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You may also want to paste the actual error being logged. That’ll help anyone trying to help you. Just a thought.

Comment: Please rewrite your code, and format it properly. You waste too much effort to split your code into multiple line, waste too much + "..." + "...". for no reason. Your code is a tangle one, can not read it until reformat it manually.

Comment: sorry i reformated it please re check it

Comment: Looking at your formatted code, my eyes hurt.  My suggestion is to add more carraige returns.  As a minimum, one should be able to make out the start of the from and where clauses.  I certainly can't.

Comment: May I suggest that you take the time to reformat your code to get rid of all those sub selects.  Your entire from clause could be written without a single one.  `from 
  login_session ls 
  inner join login_session_property a on ls.session_id=a.session_id and a.property_name='branchID'
  inner join login_session_property b on ls.session_id=b.session_id and b.property_name='orderChannel'
  inner join login_session_property c on ls.session_id=c.session_id and c.property_name='orderRootDiv'
  inner join branch bc on a.branch_id=bc.branch_id`

Comment: The question is tagged "mysql" but this isn't MySQL syntax, it is clearly Oracle syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate words with spaces when you concatenate strings.

For example between the end of line 3 `as branch_id` with the beginning of line 4 `from login_session_property`. This would become `as branch_idfrom login_session_property`. See the error? This doesn't make sense.

Just make sure you add a space at the end of each line to make sure you are separating words, when the whole string is built. The end of line 3 should look like `as branch_id` <-- an extra space at the end here.

You have several lines with the same mistake.

Comment: I was going to suggest using a heredoc to avoid such ugly string concatenations, then realized java doesn't have anything like that... well that stinks...